# uber requestRide() method Response Error 401: Unauthorized

Tags: android, uber-api

I am getting Error when I try to call **requestRide()** method on Uber api. The response body is null and the response message is "Unauthorized" with error code 401; whereas the onResponse() callback method is executing but onFailure() callback method is not executing.

Here is my code for calling requestRide() and implementing the callback interface...

```
private void requestForNewRide(RidesService service, int position){
        RideRequestParameters rideRequestParameters = new RideRequestParameters.Builder().setPickupCoordinates(PICKUP_LATITUDE, PICKUP_LONGITUDE)
                .setProductId(productIds.get(position))
                .setFareId(fareIds.get(position))
                .setDropoffCoordinates(DROPOFF_LATITUDE, DROPOFF_LONGITUDE)
                .build();
        service.requestRide(rideRequestParameters).enqueue(new Callback<Ride>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Ride> call, Response<Ride> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(CustomActivity.this, "Request ride success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    try {
                        //ride details
                        String rideId = response.body().getRideId();
                        String rideStatus = response.body().getStatus();
                        Integer rideEta = response.body().getEta();                           //estimated time of arrival in min
                        Float rideSurgeMultiplier = response.body().getSurgeMultiplier();     //rise in price
                        Driver rideDriver = response.body().getDriver();
                        Location rideLocation = response.body().getLocation();
                        Vehicle rideVehicle = response.body().getVehicle();

                        //ride driver details
                        String driverName = rideDriver.getName();
                        String driverPhoneNumber = rideDriver.getPhoneNumber();
                        String driverPictureUri = rideDriver.getPictureUrl();
                        Float driverRating = rideDriver.getRating();

                        //ride Location details
                        Float rideLocationLatitude = rideLocation.getLatitude();
                        Float rideLocationLongitude = rideLocation.getLongitude();
                        Integer rideLocationBearing = rideLocation.getBearing();

                        //ride Vehicle details
                        String rideVehicleLicencePlate = rideVehicle.getLicensePlate();
                        String rideVehicleMake = rideVehicle.getMake();
                        String rideVehicleModel = rideVehicle.getModel();
                        String rideVehiclePictureUrl = rideVehicle.getPictureUrl();

                        //Log
                        Log.d("uberridedetails", "rideId: " + rideId);
                        Log.d("uberridedetails", "rideStatus: " + rideStatus);
                        Log.d("uberridedetails", "rideEta: " + rideEta);
                        Log.d("uberridedetails", "rideSurgeMultiplier: " + rideSurgeMultiplier);
                        Log.d("uberridedetails", "driverName: " + driverName);
                        Log.d("uberridedetails", "driverPhoneNumber: " + driverPhoneNumber);
                        Log.d("uberridedetails", "driverPictureUri: " + driverPictureUri);
                        Log.d("uberridedetails", "driverRating: " + driverRating);
                        Log.d("uberridedetails", "rideLocationLatitude: " + rideLocationLatitude);
                        Log.d("uberridedetails", "rideLocationLongitude: " + rideLocationLongitude);
                        Log.d("uberridedetails", "rideLocationBearing: " + rideLocationBearing);
                        Log.d("uberridedetails", "rideVehicleLicencePlate: " + rideVehicleLicencePlate);
                        Log.d("uberridedetails", "rideVehicleMake: " + rideVehicleMake);
                        Log.d("uberridedetails", "rideVehicleModel: " + rideVehicleModel);
                        Log.d("uberridedetails", "rideVehiclePictureUrl: " + rideVehiclePictureUrl);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(CustomActivity.this, "Error: "+response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Ride> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(CustomActivity.this, "Failed to request ride", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

I have already checked the param productId and FareId is valid, which I am getting from the api itself (by calling estimateRide() I get Price object from that I have got the fareId. And by calling getProducts() on RideService object I have got the productId.

This is the code for set up...

```
 SessionConfiguration config = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
                .setClientId(getResources().getString(R.string.client_id))
                .setRedirectUri(getResources().getString(R.string.redirect_url))
                .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX)
                .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS, Scope.REQUEST, Scope.REQUEST_RECEIPT))
                .build();
        UberSdk.initialize(config);
```

And ...

```
LoginCallback loginCallback = new LoginCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLoginCancel() {
                // User canceled login
                Toast.makeText(CustomActivity.this, "User canceled login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoginError(@NonNull AuthenticationError error) {
                // Error occurred during login
                Toast.makeText(CustomActivity.this, "Error occurred during login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoginSuccess(@NonNull AccessToken accessToken) {
                // Successful login!  The AccessToken will have already been saved.
                Toast.makeText(CustomActivity.this, "Successful login!  The AccessToken will have already been saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                createSession();
            }
            @Override
            public void onAuthorizationCodeReceived(@NonNull String authorizationCode) {
                Toast.makeText(CustomActivity.this, "Authorization code received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                createSession();
            }
        };
        AccessTokenManager accessTokenManager = new AccessTokenManager(getApplicationContext());
        LoginManager loginManager = new LoginManager(accessTokenManager, loginCallback);
        loginManager.setRedirectForAuthorizationCode(true);
        loginManager.login(this);
        mAccessTokenManager = accessTokenManager;
        mLoginManager = loginManager;
```

**Note1:**  These are the scopes I am using...

```
Scope.PROFILE, Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS, Scope.REQUEST, Scope.REQUEST_RECEIPT
```

**Note2:**  I am logging in with my developer account.

Let me know if I should mention any other details.

Comment: Do you still have authentication problem?   I can see from our logs you have managed to get the valid access token: https://www.uber.com/en-IN#access_token=KA.eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoyLCJpZCI6Ik1XOX*******. Also there is a succesifull ride request done on: "@timestamp": "2017-10-16T13:41:19.318Z".  Can you please update your question with resolution - and what was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely I have found out the solution on my own.

I noticed that the `onLoginSuccess()` callback method is being called only when I am using GENERAL SCOPEs.

Whenever I am using a RESTRICTED SCOPE, the method is not being called, instead another callback method named `onAuthorizationCodeReceived()` is being called.

Then I have found out, ***whenever the `onAuthorizationCodeReceived()` method is called, there is no access token saved in the AccessTokenManager object***. Thus without the access token, when I try to request a ride Error returns "Unauthorized".

So, I tried to figure out how to generate Access token using the authorization code. I found no doc regarding this process in the Android section. Then I have found out the solution in the REST web service api.

Here is the [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769210/how-to-get-uber-access-token-using-authorization-code-in-login-callback/46782995#46782995) of my answer...

**NOTE:** There is no mention of the callback method onAuthorizationCodeReceived() in the Uber Doc.