# How to get UBER Access token using authorization code in Login Callback

Tags: java, android, uber-api

I am configuring uber sdk with Request scope (Restricted). In the LoginManager callback method onAuthorizationCodeReceived() I am getting authorizationCode as a parameter, whereas the onLoginSuccess() callback method is not being called.

Here is my code...

```
config = initialiseUberSDK();
accessTokenManager = new AccessTokenManager(this);
loginManager = new LoginManager(accessTokenManager,
    new LoginCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onLoginCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(CustomActivity2.this, "Login cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoginError(@NonNull AuthenticationError error) {
            Toast.makeText(CustomActivity2.this,
                                "Error: "+error.name(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoginSuccess(@NonNull AccessToken accessToken) {
            Toast.makeText(CustomActivity2.this, "Login success",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                        createSession();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthorizationCodeReceived(@NonNull String authorizationCode) {
            Toast.makeText(CustomActivity2.this, "Your Auth code is: "+authorizationCode,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
             }
         },
         config,
         1113).setRedirectForAuthorizationCode(true);
     customButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
     customButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         loginManager.login(CustomActivity2.this);
     }
 });
```

And here is the initialiseUberSDK() method...

```
 private SessionConfiguration initialiseUberSDK() {
        config = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
                .setClientId(getResources().getString(R.string.client_id))
//                .setServerToken(getResources().getString(R.string.server_token))
//                .setClientSecret(getResources().getString(R.string.client_secret))
                .setRedirectUri(getResources().getString(R.string.redirect_url))
                .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX)
                .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS, Scope.REQUEST))
                .build();
//        UberSdk.initialize(config);
        return config;
    }
```

Here onLoginSuccess() method never being called. Only onAuthorizationCodeReceived() method is being called (with access token object being null).

My question is

> how to generate access token using the authorization code?

Below is the java doc of the onAuthorizationCodeReceived() method...

*

> public void onAuthorizationCodeReceived(@NonNull String
>   authorizationCode)
>
> **Description copied from interface:** LoginCallback Called when authorization code has been returned to the redirect uri. AccessToken
>   must be retrieved using Client Secret, see
>   https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication#section-step-two-receive-redirect
>   Specified by:
>       onAuthorizationCodeReceived in interface LoginCallback
>        Parameters:
>       **authorizationCode** - the authorizationCode that can be used to retrieve AccessToken

*

Answer (score 0):

You posted SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731239/uber-requestride-method-response-error-401-unauthorized) as well. Plase, use the authorization code as per this sample you submitted - because it is confirmed from our logs that you managed to get a valid access token as a response (KA.eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoyLCJ*****). Also, you successfully initiate new ride request. So code you used to achieve it is a valid code.
If this does not answer your question please check Android SDK [sample](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/request-button-sample/src/main/java/com/uber/sdk/android/rides/samples/SampleActivity.java).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right that I manage to get the access token using the authorization code. I have gone through your REST web service doc and found out that using a POST request to server with a valid authorization code, I can get the required parameters to generate an access token.

Here is my updated code for getting auth code in the callback and request server using HTTP POST method to generate access token...

```
loginManager = new LoginManager(accessTokenManager,
                new LoginCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onLoginCancel() {
                        Toast.makeText(CustomActivity2.this, "Login cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoginError(@NonNull AuthenticationError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(CustomActivity2.this,
                                "Error: "+error.name(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoginSuccess(@NonNull AccessToken accessToken) {
                        Toast.makeText(CustomActivity2.this, "Login success",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthorizationCodeReceived(@NonNull String authorizationCode) {
                        Toast.makeText(CustomActivity2.this, "Your Auth code is: "+authorizationCode,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                        Ion.with(getApplicationContext())
                                .load("POST", "https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token")
                                .setBodyParameter("client_id",getResources().getString(R.string.client_id))
                                .setBodyParameter("client_secret",getResources().getString(R.string.client_secret))
                                .setBodyParameter("grant_type","authorization_code")
                                .setBodyParameter("redirect_uri",getResources().getString(R.string.redirect_url))
                                .setBodyParameter("code",authorizationCode)
                                .setBodyParameter("scope","profile history request")
                                .asString()
                                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                                        try {
                                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                                            if (result.contains("error")) {
                                                String error = jsonObject.getString("error");
                                                Toast.makeText(CustomActivity2.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }else {
                                                String accessTokenTemp = jsonObject.getString("access_token");
                                                String expiresInTemp = jsonObject.getString("expires_in");
                                                String lastAuthenticatedTemp = jsonObject.getString("last_authenticated");
                                                String refreshTokenTemp = jsonObject.getString("refresh_token");
                                                String scopeTemp = jsonObject.getString("scope");
                                                String tokenTypeTemp = jsonObject.getString("token_type");

                                                AccessTokenManager accessTokenManager = new AccessTokenManager(getApplicationContext());
                                                int expirationTime = Integer.parseInt(expiresInTemp);
                                                List<Scope> scopes = Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.HISTORY, Scope.REQUEST);
                                                String token = accessTokenTemp;
                                                String refreshToken = refreshTokenTemp;
                                                String tokenType = tokenTypeTemp;
                                                AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(expirationTime, scopes, token, refreshToken, tokenType);
                                                accessTokenManager.setAccessToken(accessToken);

                                                if (accessTokenManager.getAccessToken() != null){
                                                    createSession();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } catch (JSONException e1) {
                                            e1.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                },
                config,
                1113).setRedirectForAuthorizationCode(true);
```

The problem with the API is there is no mention of requesting server to POST method for getting the access token. Also there is no mention of the onAuthorizationCodeReceived() callback method in the doc.

And also, there should be a JAVA interface for doing this operation as everything else is doing that (OR at least in the doc they should mention the process).

Whatever, I have found out the solution yesterday evening on my own (14 hours ego) and now (today morning) I am posting the solution. Hope, this will help someone.

**NOTE:** I have used ION library as a network client.